# Both mathematical and Greek characters in graph label using R

Tags: r, graphing

I want a graph about about drug exposure to have the x-axis title "area under the curve (uM*min)", but I'm flummoxed about how to both have an actual Greek letter μ instead of the "u" and a times symbol (×) instead of "*".

I've tried

```
 plot(1:10, 1:10, 
 xlab = expression("AUC ("*mu*"M"*\times*"min)"))
```

but that doesn't work. I tried

```
 xlab = expression(paste("AUC ("*mu*"M", \times, "min)")))
```

and no go there, either. I thought of using "&#215;" somehow, but I don't see how that would work without R thinking that I've commented out the rest of that line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think there are other solutions, but just noting R would understand that a quoted `#` is not meant as a start of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution using unicode: `plot(0,0, xlab = "AUC (\U03BCM \U00D7 min)")`

[image]

---

Another solution using `expression`: `plot(0,0, xlab = expression(AUC~"("*mu*M %*% min*")"))`